# Boost: Big graphs & Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, graph, boost-graph

I need to create a *directed* graph that can be quite large from a big dataset. I know these things for sure:

- Each node has at most K outgoing edges
- I have a list (`unordered_map`) of N >> K nodes
- The graph is build by comparing all nodes with each other (yes, O(N^2) unfortunately)

Thinking about it, I would parallelize the graph creation using `std::thread`, and I was wondering if this could be done via Boost Graph Library.

If I use the adjacency matrix, it should be possible to preallocate the matrix (K*N elements), and hence it would be thread-safe to insert all adjacent nodes.

I've read that BGL could be thread-unsafe, but the posts I've found are three years old.

Do you know if it's possible to do what I'm thinking? Do you recommend doing otherwise?

Cheers!

Comment: AFAIK BGL is and will be thread unsafe, if needed it's something can be added by library user (price to pay for everyone else is too high). That said if I remember well there is a parallel version of that library (check it out). Preallocation is **always** a good thing (even when not working with threads) but it's not strictly necessary, you may just make parallel each iteration of the loop and then (synchronously) put results all together. I can't imagine more without any code but yes...I suppose it's viable.

Comment: We don't know your problem space but my gut tells me optimizing the graph creation to be `< O(N^2)` would be a better use of your time.  Parallelizing would only delay the inevitable moment where creating the graph is just not feasible.  You're mentioning large datasets, how large is `N`?

Comment: N may get up to 50M, with K < 50 (usually can be 5-10). I cannot imagine to make it less than `O(N^2)`, since I need to apply a function on two strings such that `f : string x string -> unsigned int`. (each node in the graph represents a string) Any hint, as usual, is more than welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Almost any graph algorithm in BGL needs a mapping: vertex -> int which assigns to each vertex a unique integer within the range [0, num_vertices(g) ). This mapping is known as "vertex_index" and is usually accessible as property_map.

Having said that, I can assume your vertices are already integers or associated with some integers (e.g. your unordered_map has some extra field in "mapped_type"). Even better (for performance and memory) if your input vertices are stored in continuous tight array, e.g. std::vector, then indexing is natural.

If vertices are [associated with] integers, your best choice for memory-tight graph is "[Compressed Sparse Row Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/compressed_sparse_row.html)". The graph is immutable, so you need to populate edges container before you generate a graph.

As ravenspoint explained, your best choice is to equip each thread with its own local container of results and lock the central container only when merging the local result into the final one. Such strategy is implemented lock-less by TBB template [tbb::parallel_reduce](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_reduce_func.htm). So your full code for graph building can look roughly as below:

```
#include "tbb/blocked_range2d.h"
#include "tbb/parallel_reduce.h"
#include "boost/graph/compressed_sparse_row_graph.hpp"

typedef something vertex; //e.g.something is integer giving index of a real data

class EdgeBuilder
{
public:
    typedef std::pair<int,int> edge;
    typedef std::vector<edge> Edges;
    typedef ActualStorage Input;

    EdgeBuilder(const Input & input):_input(input){} //OPTIONAL: reserve some space in _edges
    EdgeBuilder( EdgeBuilder& parent, tbb::split ): _input(parent.input){} // reserve something

    void operator()( const const tbb::blocked_range2d<size_t>& r ) 
    { 
        for( size_t i=r.rows().begin(); i!=r.rows().end(); ++i ){
            for( size_t j=r.cols().begin(); j!=r.cols().end(); ++j ) {
                //I assume you provide some function to compute existence
                if (my_func_edge_exist(_input,i, j))
                    m_edges.push_back(edge(i,j));
            }
        }        
    } 

    //merges local results from two TBB threads
    void join( EdgeBuilder& rhs ) 
    {
        m_edges.insert( m_edges.end(), rhs.m_edges.begin(), rhs.m_edges.end() ); 
    }

    Edges _edges; //for a given interval of vertices
    const Input & _input;
};

//full flow:  
boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph<>* build_graph( const Storage & vertices)
{
    EdgeBuilder builder(vertices);
    tbb::blocked_range2d<size_t,size_t> range(0,vertices.size(), 100, //row grain size 
                                              0,vertices.size(), 100); //col grain size
    tbb::parallel_reduce(range, builder);

    boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph<> 
      theGraph = new boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph<> 
                        (boost::edges_are_unsorted_multi_pass_t, 
                         builder._edges.begin(), builder._edges.end(), 
                         vertices.size() );
    return theGraph;
}
```

Comment: I am more inclined now to use TBB. I've implemented the serial operations and node builder, as well as the edge creation function. I will proceed to try TBB!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should break your goal down into two separate sub-goals.

1. Create the links between nodes by doing the N * ( N - 1 ) tests of pairs of nodes.  You appear to have an idea of how to break this up into independent threads.  Store the results in a data structure that you know is thread safe, without worrying about the mysteries of boost:graph.
2. Create the boost::graph from your nodes and ( just created ) links.

A note about storing the links created in each thread:  It is not so easy to find a suitable thread safe data structure.  If you use a STL dynamically allocated structure, then you have to worry about making a thread safe allocator which is a challenge.  If you pre-allocate, then there is a lot of meessy code to handle the allocations.  So, I would suggest storing the links created by each thread in a separate data structure, so they do not have to be thread safe.  When the links are all created, you can loop over the links created by each thread one by one.

A slightly more efficient design could be imagined, but will require a lot of arcane knowledge about thread safety.  The design I propose can be implemented without arcane knowledge or tricky code and will therefore be implemented more quickly and more robustly and will be easier to maintain.

Comment: But in this case, when creating the graph I'll be wasting a lot of memory. Unless, for instance, I can merge (by moving) all nodes into a the graph. Do you know if `boost::graph` supports this union by moving?

Comment: The nodes consume most memory, but they do so however you design this.  The links you create consume a small amount of memory ( references to two nodes for each link ) which is duplicated for a brief moment while you copy them from thread storage to the graph.  If you break the link creation task into many small tasks, then this "wasted" memory can be as small as you wish.

Comment: You make a good point, in this case I would be better of reducing with a merge operation (comfortably associative and commutative). I will give it a try, thanks!